# Strain mapping sphere to plane

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

I need general indications or guidance.

I do not know how to map a surface $ z = \sin (\pi x) \sin (\pi y), (x,0,\pi), (y,0,\pi)$ to a unit square. Nor do I know how to map a quadrant of a unit sphere:

$$ (x_1,y_1,z_1) = ( \cos(u) \cos(v), \cos(u)\sin(v), \sin(u)),\quad ( u,0, \pi/2), (v,0,\pi/2)$$ 
with metric
$ ds^2 = du^2 + \cos^2(u) dv^2 $ onto a  square flat patch $$ (x_2,y_2,z_2) = ( u \pi/2 ,v \pi/2, 0 ), \quad (u,0,1), (v,0,1), $$ where one edge totally shrinks to zero in length.

Since it does not preserve lengths / angles, there is no isometry but E,F,G etc. need to be further differentiated and set to future strained shape. I seek to find what relations exist between coefficients of first/second  fundamental forms and their successive partial derivatives that bring about strain/dilation, shown by change of length and area differentials?

I have in mind Beltrami's first differential parameter, i.e., Laplacian of Gauss curvature and also  the von Karman's strain compatibility relations from Laminate theory in mechanics of materials.

At least, let me know where my question makes no sense.

Comment: This is unclear because *we don't know* what $E$, $F$, and $G$ represent.  It would be better if you provided some context.

Comment: E,F and G are coefficients of the first fundamental form in classical surface theory built on parameters u and v.

Comment: You have already expressed your surface $z = sin (\pi x) sin (\pi y), (x,0,1), (y,0,1)$ (I assume you did not mean to have $\pi$ in both places) essentially as a mapping between the points $(x,y)$ in the unit square and the points $(x,y, sin (\pi x) sin (\pi y))$ in your surface. The mapping is a simple projection. So we don't understand your statement "I do not know how to map...." Are you looking for a _different_ mapping that has certain properties? What properties?

Comment: @Matt, Yes, it is a projection on x-y plane. (Unless pi is in both arguments, we do not have four common edges x=0,x=1,y=0,y=1, but it is not so central to the question).

Comment: Knowing 3-space parametrization/ embeddings in source and target surfaces is not what is required, but when they are given, ( E,F,G,L,M and N) set for  source and target are calculated, to find procedure by which we get from one set to the other or transform first set to the second one and vice-versa.

Comment: I am referring for example to what intrinsic operations need to be done on E,F and G and their partial derivatives to influence how the surface can dilate, bend and twist to get it placed at any other desired location.This is similar to what "FlatLanders" do, mentioned in Relativity theory.

Comment: So this question really seems to be about the parameters E,F,G,L,M,N. If you could provide the mathematical definitions of those parameters, then people here could more easily help you.

Comment: @anorton In differential geometry, $E,F,G$ are standard notation for the coefficients of the [first fundamental form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_fundamental_form). (This is just FYI, not to argue about the closure.)